# RelaxNG or XSD schema validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xsd, xsd-validation, relaxng

I'd like to do RelaxNG (preferred) or XSD (if I have to) schema validation in client-side JavaScript.  Any good libraries for this?  Google finds [jsrelaxngvalidator](http://code.google.com/p/jsrelaxngvalidator/) but I'm having trouble getting it running and it seems unmaintained.  Target browsers are Firefox and Chrome only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartClient can load an XSD and generate a form for editing the data, complete with validation rules and user friendly error messages:

http://www.smartclient.com/#xmlSchemaImport

You can also serialize the data that the user inputs and produce an XML document that conforms to the XSD (correctly namespaced and all that) using DataSource.xmlSerialize().

http://www.smartclient.com/docs/8.0/a/b/c/go.html#method..DataSource.xmlSerialize

This functionality is all implemented in the browser (no server component) and is all in the free OSS version (SmartClient LGPL).

Note this particular feature is part of a much larger system that may or may not fit your needs - SmartClient is primarily for large scale enterprise business applications.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be "No": we got jsrelaxngvalidator working in the end, but it has bizarre restrictions on what it supports, requires lots of libraries to run (incl. a custom SAX parser also in beta) and does weird stuff like downloading 18 XSLTs over the wire to preprocess the schemas, so we gave up it.

Instead, I rewrote the schema as [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/), with client-side validation using [JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV).  The learning curve was a bit steep, but it's working nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

There now appears to be a TypeScript project that tackles this problem: https://github.com/mangalam-research/salve